# Effects of including the square term in a regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

my question is the following: when including squared terms in a linear regression, and possibily interactions of those with other controls, should I expect a specific change in significance of the estimates? For example, should I expect that coefficients are on average less significant because I am trying to estimate more of them (even if they refer to the same underlying variables)?

Comment: I think we may need more details here. When you say "the estimates" which estimates precisely do you mean? Coefficients of the linear term for which you added the quadratic, some other coefficient, the predictions from the model, something else? Best to edit it into the question.

Comment: Literally anything could happen, from no changes to huge increases to huge decreases in significance.  This is well discussed in many of our threads concerned about changes of significance: the issue is not confined to including quadratic terms, but extends to including *any* other collection of terms in a regression.